# Changing a gridview's datasource based on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm struggling a lot and I hope someone can help me please.

I have a 4 dropdownlists, a search button and a normal gridview with a basic SQLdataConnection.

The SQLdataConnection is a stored procedure that retrieves 3 tables based on 4 parameters. These 3 tables are then joined together into the gridview.

BUT

One of the dropdownlists has the options of *Total, Fast* and *Slow*. So based on which option the user chooses the respective table should be loaded into the gridview when the search button is pressed. (So if total is chosen, the total table should be loaded into the gridview)

I don't know if the SQLdataConnection should be changed with each option to show only the appropriate table.

Below is a copy of the html of the dropdowns and gridview as well as the code behind.

```html
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: right" class="pad-right-0">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="selSeconds" runat="server" CssClass="selectbox select-chr" Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="selHours" runat="server" CssClass="selectbox select-chr" Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="selMerchantId" runat="server" CssClass="selectbox select-chr" Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="selTableType" runat="server" CssClass="selectbox select-chr" Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-danger tip-s medium grey" ValidationGroup="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, btnSearch %>" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-danger tip-s medium grey" ValidationGroup="Search" onclick="btnExportToExcel_Click" Text="Export to excel" ImageUrl="images/Excel.png" AlternateText="<%$Resources:Resource, lblExportExcel %>"
      CausesValidation="false" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqrdMerchantId" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:Resource, lblRequired %>" ControlToValidate="selMerchantId" ForeColor="Red" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMerchantId" runat="server" Value="0" />
<asp:GridView ID="gridSpeedAnalysis" runat="server" DataSourceID="gridSqlConnection">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="gridSqlConnection" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UserName"] == null || Session["UserType"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

        LoadDropDowns();

    }



    private void LoadDropDowns()
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item;
        selSeconds.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Select Second", "0"));
        int index = 1;
        for (int Second = 0; Second <= 10; Second++)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(Second.ToString(), Second.ToString());
            selSeconds.Items.Insert(index, li);
            index++;
        }

        item = selSeconds.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        selSeconds.SelectedIndex = selSeconds.Items.IndexOf(item);

        if (Session["UserType"] != null && (Session["UserType"].ToString().ToLower() == "System Administrator".ToLower()))
        {
            selMerchantId.DataSource = BOL.MerchantGroup.Load();
            selMerchantId.DataTextField = "Description";
            selMerchantId.DataValueField = "MerchantId";
            selMerchantId.DataBind();
            selMerchantId.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Select Group" });
            rqrdMerchantId.InitialValue = "0";
        }
        else if (Session["UserType"].ToString().ToLower() == "Head Office".ToLower())
        {
            BOL.MerchantGroup group = new BOL.MerchantGroup(int.Parse(hdnMerchantId.Value));
            selMerchantId.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem { Value = hdnMerchantId.Value, Text = group.Description });
        }

        DataTable dt = BOL.Merchant.GetDropdownByMerhcantGroupId(int.Parse(Session["MerchantGroupId"].ToString()));

        selMerchantId.DataSource = dt;
        selMerchantId.DataTextField = "Name";
        selMerchantId.DataValueField = "MerchantId";
        selMerchantId.DataBind();

        selTableType.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem {Text = "Total"});
        selTableType.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem {Text = "Fast" });
        selTableType.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem {Text = "Slow" });

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

    }
```

Comment: Start by putting `LoadDropDowns();` in an `IsPostBack` check. Then create a single method that retrieves the data based on the parameters and bind the result to the GridView.

Comment: Okey! but that single method you mentioned; would it make sense to create it in the click event of search button?

Comment: It can be in the click also. But if you also want to reference it in page load at some point then it's easier to create a method.

Comment: last question I tried earlier to create such a method and said something like: if(selTableType.Text ==  "Total") {gridSpeedAnalysis.DataSource = ?} Am I on the right path?

Comment: Yes, that can work. As long as the columns are the same (or only use autogenerated columns)